# javaのジェネリックで?あり・なしの違い

Tags: java

```
class Hoge<T>{ }
```

上記のClass宣言があるとして

```
Hoge x1;
Hoge<?> x2;
```

変数宣言で?ありと?なしで宣言できるみたいなのですが、この違いは何でしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Hoge x1`は後方互換のために残されているだけで、`Hoge<?> x2`と同様と記憶しています。
確か、JavaのGenericsはコンパイル時に型パラメータ情報は落ちた記憶があります。

Comment: ?を説明しているサイトはあるのですが、?なしを説明してるサイトが見つからないので疑問に思っていました。互換の為に残っているだけと言うことですね。ありがとうございます

Comment: FYI: [raw type](http://www.ne.jp/asahi/hishidama/home/tech/java/generics.html#raw_type)という名前が正式名です。検索キーワードにどうぞ。